# Wait ten second and if anyone don't touch to screen restart to application

Tags: android

I am doing application in android and I want to add this future in my application.Wait ten second and if anyone don't touch to screen restart to application in android how can I do it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Start a Timer to increment the time & if it reaches 10 seconds do your Task as desired

  ```
  timer = new Timer();
  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

              public void run() {                         
                     if(userInteractionTimeout==10)
                     {
                        // Do your task
                     }
                    userInteractionTimeout++;
                  }
              }, 0,1000);
  ```
- override onUserInteraction() in your Activity - reset the timer

  ```
  @Override
  public void onUserInteraction() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onUserInteraction();

    userInteractionTimeout=0;

    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"User Interaction : "+userInteractionTimeout);

  }
  ```

Comment: I am new in android, can you show in example?

Comment: Updated my answer.Check it

Comment: Your coding is runing thank you but  I have a another problem When I passing from third Activity to MainActivity Second Activity features still running how can I stop second Activity When I passing second Activity to Third Activity.